# What are coarse and fine labels in Cifar10?

Tags: machine-learning

I have came across the CIFAR10 dataset in binary. It says there are two labels, a coarse label and a fine label. Can anyone explain the difference between the two, as the format states:

<1 x coarse label><1 x fine label><3072 x pixel>

<1 x coarse label><1 x fine label><3072 x pixel>

Thank You!
Zan,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain only CIFAR100 has both coarse labels and fine labels.
CIFAR10 only has one set of labels: airplane, automobile, bird, cat, deer, dog, frog, horse, ship, truck.

For CIFAR100 coarse labels are the superclass to which the image belongs to, like: fish, flowers or insects. Fine labels are the subclass, like:
bee, beetle, butterfly, caterpillar...

See https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html for a complete list.